# OutOfMemoryError crashes systemui when accessing Recent Apps only on Marshmallow

Tags: android, crash, out-of-memory, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm working on an Android app that works well except when accessing the recent apps list on Android 6.0+. When I tap the recent apps button while my app is open, com.android.systemui will crash with the following stacktrace:

```
03-31 15:40:22.291 23442-23442/? E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
03-31 15:40:22.318 23442-23442/? E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 119596108 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 57MB until OOM
                                                         at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                         at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                         at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
                                                         at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                                                         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2598)
                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2503)
                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:806)
                                                         at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getDrawable(ApplicationPackageManager.java:836)
                                                         at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.loadUnbadgedItemIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2069)
                                                         at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.loadItemIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2049)
                                                         at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:155)
                                                         at android.content.pm.ComponentInfo.loadDefaultIcon(ComponentInfo.java:184)
                                                         at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.loadUnbadgedItemIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2072)
                                                         at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.loadItemIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2049)
                                                         at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:155)
                                                         at com.android.systemui.recents.misc.SystemServicesProxy.getActivityIcon(SystemServicesProxy.java:488)
                                                         at com.android.systemui.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoader.getAndUpdateActivityIcon(RecentsTaskLoader.java:407)
                                                         at com.android.systemui.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoadPlan.executePlan(RecentsTaskLoadPlan.java:238)
                                                         at com.android.systemui.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoader.loadTasks(RecentsTaskLoader.java:477)
                                                         at com.android.systemui.recents.Recents.preloadIcon(Recents.java:690)
                                                         at com.android.systemui.recents.Recents.preCacheThumbnailTransitionBitmapAsync(Recents.java:699)
                                                         at com.android.systemui.recents.Recents.preloadRecentsInternal(Recents.java:402)
                                                         at com.android.systemui.recents.Recents.preloadRecents(Recents.java:382)
                                                         at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar.preloadRecents(BaseStatusBar.java:1139)
                                                         at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar$7.onTouch(BaseStatusBar.java:1102)
                                                         at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9296)
                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
                                                         at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9520)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4238)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4104)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3650)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3703)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3795)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3677)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3852)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3650)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3703)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3677)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3650)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5932)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5906)
                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(Vie
03-31 15:40:22.321 23442-23442/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.android.systemui, PID: 23442
                                                   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 119596108 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 57MB until OOM
                                                       at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
                                                       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                                                       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2598)
                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2503)
                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:806)
                                                       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getDrawable(ApplicationPackageManager.java:836)
                                                       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.loadUnbadgedItemIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2069)
                                                       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.loadItemIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2049)
                                                       at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:155)
                                                       at android.content.pm.ComponentInfo.loadDefaultIcon(ComponentInfo.java:184)
                                                       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.loadUnbadgedItemIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2072)
                                                       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.loadItemIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2049)
                                                       at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:155)
                                                       at com.android.systemui.recents.misc.SystemServicesProxy.getActivityIcon(SystemServicesProxy.java:488)
                                                       at com.android.systemui.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoader.getAndUpdateActivityIcon(RecentsTaskLoader.java:407)
                                                       at com.android.systemui.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoadPlan.executePlan(RecentsTaskLoadPlan.java:238)
                                                       at com.android.systemui.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoader.loadTasks(RecentsTaskLoader.java:477)
                                                       at com.android.systemui.recents.Recents.preloadIcon(Recents.java:690)
                                                       at com.android.systemui.recents.Recents.preCacheThumbnailTransitionBitmapAsync(Recents.java:699)
                                                       at com.android.systemui.recents.Recents.preloadRecentsInternal(Recents.java:402)
                                                       at com.android.systemui.recents.Recents.preloadRecents(Recents.java:382)
                                                       at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar.preloadRecents(BaseStatusBar.java:1139)
                                                       at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar$7.onTouch(BaseStatusBar.java:1102)
                                                       at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9296)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
                                                        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9520)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4238)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4104)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3650)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3703)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3795)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3677)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3852)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3650)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3703)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3677)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3650)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5932)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.
0
```

Occasionally the recent apps list will successfully display, but there is a long lag between tapping the button and the list displaying. Attempting to scroll through recent apps is also very slow.

I'm not sure how to go about debugging this problem and I would appreciate any suggestions. Device monitor suggests that the system has plenty of memory to work with.

Comment: If we assume the methods in the stack trace are fairly literal, the problem appears to be in loading your activity's icon (`getActivityIcon()`). Is there anything unusual about the icon for this activity?

Comment: Good catch! Turns out I forgot to properly resize the launcher icon and it was crashing on marshmallow phones. Not sure why it didn't have the problem on other versions of Android.