# Unfortunately, System UI has stopped after closing my app in Samsung Galaxy S6

Tags: android

I'm developing one app in android, it works perfectly and smoothly with no any issue.

Problem:

When I close my app, the phone starts giving me error :

> Unfortunately, System UI has stopped

and when I close the dialog it gives me another error until I uninstall my app.

**P.S**  I have tested my application in Galaxy Tab S2 and LG V10 and some other phones and it didn't give me any error. Problem occur only in Samsung Galaxy S6.

When the phone gives me the error, It logs this in logcat:

```
06-19 17:38:26.481 26821-26821/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.android.systemui.recents, PID: 26821
                                               java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 20332 byte allocation with 13472 free bytes and 13KB until OOM
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Array.createMultiArray(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:335)
                                                   at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getAppIconAlphaRelativeScale(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2989)
                                                   at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getThemeIconWithBG(ApplicationPackageManager.java:3107)
                                                   at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getThemeIconWithBG(ApplicationPackageManager.java:3037)
                                                   at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.loadUnbadgedItemIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2867)
                                                   at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.loadItemIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2774)
                                                   at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:220)
                                                   at com.android.systemui.recents.misc.SystemServicesProxy.getActivityIcon(SystemServicesProxy.java:793)
                                                   at com.android.systemui.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoader.getAndUpdateActivityIcon(RecentsTaskLoader.java:463)
                                                   at com.android.systemui.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoadPlan.executePlan(RecentsTaskLoadPlan.java:279)
                                                   at com.android.systemui.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoader.loadTasks(RecentsTaskLoader.java:621)
                                                   at com.android.systemui.recents.Recents.onStart(Recents.java:393)
                                                   at com.android.systemui.recents.Recents.handleProxyCall(Recents.java:822)
                                                   at com.android.systemui.recents.Recents.handleProxyCall(Recents.java:744)
                                                   at com.android.systemui.recents.Recents.start(Recents.java:347)
                                                   at com.android.systemui.recents.Recents.getInstanceAndStartIfNeeded(Recents.java:322)
                                                   at com.android.systemui.recents.RecentsService.onCreate(RecentsService.java:39)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3807)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1882)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Please mention more details on the application itself, since with the current format it is very broad and might get closed. Is the application written with additional libraries or are you using the default ones? How large is the application

Comment: the application is nearly big and it uses firebase and android support libraries and some other libraries like retrofit, moshi, picasso

Comment: Problem solved! I hadn't resized launcher icon for every screen density and in recent used apps it wanted application's icon that was big so it generated out of memory exception!

Comment: Great. Please mark the question as solved then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Possible duplicate of:** [OutOfMemoryError crashes systemui when accessing Recent Apps only on Marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36343634/outofmemoryerror-crashes-systemui-when-accessing-recent-apps-only-on-marshmallow)

If not, then you will need to read more about the lifecycle of each library and the possible memory leaks. Some libraries do not automatically clear resources (like the usual Java garbage collector) and some require you to do it yourself. So make sure that you are getting rid of all the materials that you do not need upon exit.